# 14 errors in vs 2017 i think to do with it not recognising my classes

Tags: c++, syntax-error

## **i fixed it there is no need for this question now thank you for your help**

i have some errors on my program in vs 2017 that sometimes go and sometimes stay. i think it is not recognising my classes and i think its something to do with the #include not working properly as in the past i have had a single similar error before (something like ; missing before identifier) which stopped when I forward declared instead of #included please help.

**form class**

```
#pragma once
#include "IContain.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Rect.h"
class Form : public IContain
{
public:
Form();
~Form();

bool paint() override;
bool init() override;
Rect<int> Rect() override;
bool hasfocus() override;
Graphics& getgraphics() override;

bool add(IStaticControl & control) override;
bool remove(IStaticControl & control) override;

bool update() override;
pixelvec mousepos() override;

private:
std::vector<IStaticControl> controls;
```

};

**control interface class**

```
#pragma once
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "Rect.h"
#include "IContain.h"

class IStaticControl
{
public:
IStaticControl();
~IStaticControl();

//actions
virtual bool init() = 0;
virtual bool paint(Graphics& gfx) = 0;
virtual void update() = 0; // check for input that matches this' conditions. check container's input 
virtual void show() = 0;
virtual void hide() = 0;

//info
virtual Rect<int> rect() = 0;
virtual IContain& Container() = 0;
virtual bool rezizeable() = 0;
virtual bool hasfocus() = 0;
```

};

**event class**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "EventBase.h"
#include <queue>
template<typename EventArgsT>
class Myevent
{
public:


Myevent(size_t handlerCount, size_t instanceCount, std::queue<EventBase>& 
eventqueue) : Eventintances(instanceCount), handlers(handlerCount) {this->eventqueue = eventqueue};

    ~Myevent() {};


inline void raise(EventArgsT args) {eventqueue.push(Inst(args, handlers));};

size_t addhandler(void(*handler)(EventArgsT) , bool& success = false) {
    size_t size = handlers.size;
    for (size_t i; i >= size; i++) {
        if (handlers[i] = NULL) { handlers[i] = handler; success = true; 
return i; }
    }
    return 0;
};

void removehandler(size_t i) { handlers[i] = NULL };

class Inst : EventBase {
    EventArgsT args;
public:
    Inst(EventArgsT args, std::vector<void(*)(EventArgsT)>& handlers) {
        this->args = args;
        this->handlers = handlers;
    };

    // go to each function in handlers and invoke them with args
     void process() override {};

private:
    std::vector<void(*)(EventArgsT)>& handlers;
};
private:
std::vector<void(*)(EventArgsT)> handlers;

std::vector<Inst> Eventintances;

std::queue<EventBase>& eventqueue;

};
```

**control container interface class**

```
#pragma once
#include "Myevent.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "IStaticControl.h"

class IContain
{
public:


virtual bool paint() = 0;
virtual bool init() = 0;
virtual Rect<int> rect() = 0;
virtual bool hasfocus() = 0;
virtual Graphics& getgraphics() = 0;

virtual bool add(IStaticControl & control) = 0;
virtual bool remove(IStaticControl & control) = 0;

virtual bool update() = 0;
virtual pixelvec mousepos() = 0;
// same for keyboard input
private:

};
```

These are the errors

Error   C2433   'IStaticControl::IContain': 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations    c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

Error   C2433   'IStaticControl::IContain': 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations    c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'IStaticControl'   c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\icontain.h    17

Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'IStaticControl'   c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\icontain.h    18

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '&'    c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   c++ Game    c:\users\home\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\c++ game\c++ game\istaticcontrol.h  21

please help

**update:** there are 10 errors

**the code has changed very slightly**

Comment: it says 13 errors now

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Comment: What are the errors instead? Add what error you got?

Comment: i think the syntax missing before '&' for the line: virtual IContain& Container() = 0; means that it thinks that the IContain is supposed to be a forward decleration

Comment: sorry i dont know how to edit main question

Comment: how do i edit main question

Comment: You should have an `edit` hyperlink at the bottom left of your question.

Comment: i added the errors but the situation has changed and i have a bit less errors

Answer (score 2):

You have cyclic dependencies. `IStaticControl.h` includes `IContain.h`, and `IContain.h` includes `IStaticControl.h`.

(You neglected to mention the names of your files, but they can be deduced from the error messages.)

This is why `IContain` is undefined in this line:

```
virtual IContain& Container() = 0;
```

... so the compiler thinks you're trying to declare a member variable called `IContain` as an implicit `int`:

```
virtual int IContain; & Container() = 0;
```

This is why it's complaining about data members being `virtual`, implicit `int`, and syntax errors involving `;` and `&`.

Comment: im not sure how to solve

Comment: how do i solve this problem

Comment: i tried to do forward declaration of class name but it now says 9 unresolved externals

Comment: thanks for your help